# Yii2 viaTable multiple variables

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, has-many

I'm trying to find a number of `UserComment` using a `viaTable` on the table called `user_comment_user` in `Yii2`. However I can't seem to get my `variables`/`query` inserted properly.

Currently I've got two `queries` set up, to check if (on their own) they achieve the correct result, which they do.

These are the two `queries` that somehow have to be `merged` into one:

```
public function findConversation($id)
{
    $query = $this->hasMany(UserComment::classname(), ['id'=>'user_comment_id'])
        ->viaTable('user_comment_user', ['sender_id'=>'id'], function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->andWhere(['receiver_id'=>$id]);
        });
    $query2 = $this->hasMany(UserComment::classname(), ['id'=>'user_comment_id'])
        ->viaTable('user_comment_user', ['receiver_id'=>'id'], function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->andWhere(['sender_id'=>$id]);
        });
        return $query;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the expected results are?

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis I need to get all the UserComment where the sender_id is $this->id and receiver_id is $id, and the other way around. Sort by date.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was actually much simpler than I had imagined:

```
    public function findConversation($id)
    {
        $query = UserComment::find();
        $query->leftJoin('user_comment_user',      'user_comment_user.user_comment_id=user_comment.id');
        $query->where(['receiver_id'=>$this->id, 'sender_id'=>$id]);
        $query->orWhere(['receiver_id'=>$id, 'sender_id'=>$this->id]);
        $query->orderBy(['created_at'=>SORT_DESC]);

        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i'm having the same problem